# collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Tags: c++, qt

I will try to compile a systray project and got the folling error message:

```
"tmp/obj/debug_shared/moc_cao2dhl.o:C:\Qt\2010.05\qt\CAO2DHL-build-
desktop/tmp/moc/debug_shared/moc_cao2dhl.cpp:72: undefined reference to       
`Cao2DHL::trayIconClicked(QSystemTrayIcon::ActivationReason)'"
```

I am unsing QT4.7 with QT-Creator 2.0.1 and will try to use this example for a new application.

http://raphaelcruzeiro.com/2010/12/01/how-to-create-a-system-tray-icon-with-qt/

I have created the resource and make the entry for the Image !

If there is any question let me know.

Answer (score 1):

If you show your exact code it would be easier. Out of my head, please, check two things:

1. That your class `Cao2DHL` has a `Q_OBJECT` macro inside it, and
2. That the slot `trayIconClicked` has the correct `public slot:` pseudo-declaration before it in the `Cao2DHL` class.

Comment: Thx 4 help, it fixed, i have forgot to copy one line ;-(